# How can I calculate the negative horizontal offset of text in an HTML input element during horizontal overflow?

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

I have a standard HTML input element that accepts text input in my website. One important part is that I need to track the horizontal position of a given word at all times, which I'm currently achieving by creating an invisible `<span>` element, filling the span with the content of the input field, and using `getClientRects()` to find the width of the content within.

This works fine, except HTML input elements have the ability to "horizontally scroll", meaning when I keep typing at the end of the element, content at the beginning gets pushed back.

Before:
[image]

After:[image]

Is there a way to calculate the negative offset of the beginning of the input at any given moment? Manually calculating this seems a bit tricky, especially since sometimes, the offset is only equal to a partial character width.

**(edit) Clarification:**
The final goal is to calculate the position of the first character in the input field as a pixel offset, where an offset of 0 means the beginning of the text is at the beginning of the input field, while an offset of -100 means the beginning of the text is 100 pixels to the left of the start of the input field.

Simply calculating the difference between the width of the text and the width of the field won't do, since text can overflow both left and right.

Comment: I’m not sure I’m quite grasping the problem. Why isn’t it the difference between the width of the input element and the width of the text?

Comment: Not sure I understand. If you want to get the hidden offset it is simply the difference between your hidden `span` width (that contains the `input` element's value), and the `input` element's width

Comment: @AHaworth I guess because it could overflow in both directions if you are typing in the middle of the input.

Comment: @AHaworth since text could overflow both ways, and we can use the cursor to horizontally scroll through text, this solution won't give me the start location correctly. I added clarification to the question itself

Comment: Did you try `inputElement.scrollLeft`? Not sure if it works, can't try right now.

Comment: @GuillaumeBrunerie i'll give it a try and let you know

Comment: You will have a hard time getting this done as the result depends on the font face used (varying character width per font face), use of special characters in the text (visible and none visible), `box-sizing`, `padding` and `border`.  `getClientRects`  and `TextMetrics` will only provide you with the total width in pixels (graphic info) without access to the location of individual characters. Check out [MDN TextMetrics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextMetrics).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want ?

```js
//updatesize at launch
updatesize(document.querySelector("input"));

function updatesize(element){
  //get left and right scrolloverflow by subtracting scrollWidth who contains the width of the element and its overflow with the clientWidth of the element
  document.getElementById("scrolloverflow").innerHTML = element.scrollWidth - element.clientWidth;
  //scrollWidth contains the width of the element and its overflow
  document.getElementById("widthwithoverflow").innerHTML = element.scrollWidth;
  //get the scroll left value of the input element. Corresponds to the position of the first character in the input field
  //the multiplied by 10 and then divided by 10 is there to give a number with one digit after the decimal
  document.getElementById("posfirstchar").innerHTML = -(Math.floor(element.scrollLeft * 10) / 10);
}
```

```html
<!--Create a input with event listener on it :
- oninput : to update updatesize() each time we do input
- onkeydown : to catch arrow key
- onmousemove : to catch selection made by the mouse
-->
<input type="text" value="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" oninput="updatesize(this)" onkeydown="updatesize(this)" onmousemove="updatesize(this)">

<!--Debug html-->
<p>Scroll Overflow : <span id="scrolloverflow"></span> px</p>
<p>Element width (with overlow) : <span id="widthwithoverflow"></span> px</p>
<p>Position of the first character in the input field : <span id="posfirstchar"></span> px</p>
```

**Edit** : I did a pixel count to check if the position of the first character is correct.
First of all, if you want to make pixel count too, you need to make your DPI (devicePixelRatio) to 100%. (by default, this is set to 125% on Windows).

With photoshop I counted the pixels from two screenshots.
I found the expected number of pixels, in my case 140.
I attach below the image of the count.
[image: image of the pixel count]

Comment: Nice trick, honestly, but when I scroll 'sit amet' in full view I know 'Lor' is out of view and 'e' partly. With a default font-size of 13px (on Stackoverflow) I have 3.5 characters x 13px = 45.5px negative offset, not considering the font face character density. I'm not sure if subtracting `clientWidth`  from `scrollWidth` yields the proper result. Did you actually do a pixel count to verify? Also, for people to understand, explain what you did and why.

Comment: I updated my answer to put a pixel count and some comments in the code

Comment: Cool, I bookmarked this answer as I can probably use this in a project I tossed aside two years ago ([codepen](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/QWbZVmd)). Thanks for the pixel count check!